# nodejs + mysql : when to use pooled connections?

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

First of all, I know there are several similar questions, but they don't answer what I need, so let me open this new one :)

Second, this question is focused to mysql, but not limited to it, applying also to other poolable services like memcached.

As far as I know, nodejs executes the scripts single-threaded but it can create threads, so it's able to manage concurrent users in a server. That's why it makes sense to create a pool of connections.

The problem comes when I have this test api served by express, and I perform the following benchmark code:

```
ab -t 30 -c 1000 localhost/test
```

giving me the following output for single-direct-connection to the database:

```
Requests per second: 1732.07 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request: 577.344 [ms] (mean)
```

In a mysql pool with only 1 connection:

```
Requests per second: 1346.24 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request: 742.811 [ms] (mean)
```

And using a pool with 100 connections:

```
Requests per second: 662.82 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request: 1508.716 [ms] (mean)
```

Which should be the opposite, right? pooled connection with better performance.

I know the pooling management requires its time (but shouldn't be significant)  and the sql query is very simple, but... idk...

The API is something like this:

```
function test(response, request, dbc) {
  dbc.query(SQL, PARAMS, (err, rows) => {
    dbc.release();
    if(err) {
      log.error('Error while performing the query', err.code);
      return;
    }

    response.send(response, rows);
  });
}
```

where `dbc` is the database connection abstracted for single/pooled connections, and `dbc.release()` does nothing if the connection is not from a pool (to allow the same api work on direct/pooled connections with the same code, just changing an option).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Just to correct one little bit: Node.js runs non-blocking I/O operations in a single thread that allows it to serve multiple requests at the same time (interleaving) - so no need for threads to serve multiple users.

The long response time with pooling seems weird I must admit. But also the test is quite straight forward - fire a query and close the connection. I'd suppose it would start to look better towards pooling if the test did some "work" before releasing the connection. Typically there are transactions opened, multiple statements executed and so on. You could mimic this using a simple delay before releasing the connection - for example 2 seconds.

You can read more about how Node server runs requests from a single thread for example in ["Node.js: 100 new requests while still serving the first one!"](http://bytearcher.com/articles/100-new-requests-while-still-serving-the-first-one/)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying about the query being very simple, maybe that's the problem... but the performance difference (3x) is too big anyways. It's weird...

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is where i think you go wrong when you create a single connection every time you request its faster as there is just one connection to be opened over network before you execute a query, when you do the same thing with pooled connection it has to open lets say 100 connections before it starts executing a query. basically it as to acquire 100 connections before it can do anything where as in single connection it has to get only one connection. Now it doesn't make sense to close a connection every time a request ends when you are using pool. The whole point of pooling connections is to reuse connections so that you don't have to do a network hop to open a new connection every time to reduces latency and avoids network handshake on every request.

Comment: nope. 1st: when using direct connection, the connection is opened when the server is created (or when it disconnects), not when a request comes. So it behaves like 1 persisten connection. 2nd: the 100 connections of the pools are created also when the server is created, not when the request comes (there's nothing about creating/removing connexions in the test function right? only release the pooled connection)